# Passing an array as an argument in Python

Tags: python, arrays, function, switch-statement, arguments

I'm not sure if this is even possible but I'm trying to create a python program that identifies polynomials and identifies all the properties of them. I was trying to make a function similar to the switch() function, and the way that I was going to get around making hundreds of functions for each number of cases for arguments, I wanted to make one of the arguments an array, currently it's throwing me a bunch of errors and I really don't know what I'm supposed to be doing because they don't explain themselves, I've looked around and haven't found anything that works, any help would be greatly appreciated, I'm fairly certain there is a similar function in python but any articles on it are quite confusing, thank you, below is the function I was trying to make.

```
def switch(checked, check):
    for(item in check):
        if(item == check):
            return True
    
    return False
```

Comment: Your indentation is off. This could explain the syntax errors, which you should post.

Comment: Still incorrect indent: `return False`

Comment: @TimurShtatland When I copied and pasted it, the indentation was off, I have edited it so that the indentation is correct and it now looks like the code editor

Comment: @TimurShtatland I just fixed that, my apologies this is my first question on the site, I still don't know exactly how asking questions work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you mean this?

```
def switch(checked, check):
    for item in check:
        if item == checked:
            return True
    return False
```

Comment: Yes, my java habits are seeping into my python code, thank you

Answer (score 3):

If you need to simulate a switch statement you can use a helper function like this one:

```
def switch(v): yield lambda *c: v in c
```

You can then use it in a C-like style:

```
x = 3
for case in switch(x):
    if case(1,2):
       # do something
       break
    if case(3):
       # do something else
       break
    if case(4,5,7):
       # do some other thing
       break
else:
    # handle other cases
```

Or you can use if/elif/else statements:

```
x = 3
for case in switch(x):
    if   case(1,2):   # do something
    elif case(3):     # do something else
    elif case(4,5,7): # do some other thing
    else:             # handle other cases
```

Answer (score 2):

To check if something is an item of a list, you don't need to loop through the list. You can just use the [`in`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#in) operator:

```
d = ['abc', 'xyz', 1, 99]

if 'abc' in d:
    # True
    # do something

if 'mno' in d:
    # False
    # do something
```

Comment: Thank you, if I find problems with the way I've already done it, I'll try out this solution